# Visual Studio 2017 Preview exe_common.inl error while debugging attached process

Tags: python, powershell, visual-studio-debugging

I use Visual Studio 2017 Preview to debug a Python script that calls a Powershell script. While waiting for input I attach to the Powershell script and change some settings (don't remember) to continue single stepping on it. Works fine.

On a subsequent run of the Python script, I get the error "exe_common.inl not found" when the Powershell script is called. Specifically, it says "The debugger could not locate the source file 'f:\dd\vctools\crt\vcstartup\src\startup\exe_common.inl'." Powershell is called via:

```
args1 = ['powershell.exe', '.\\createsharewin.ps1', <createsharewin_args>]
p = subprocess.check_call(args1, shell=False)
```

There's no volume f: on my computer. While googling for a solution, I've noticed every mention of exe_common.inl says it's expected in that f: folder.
Restarting Visual Studio doesn't help. What am I doing wrong? How do I get back to before I attempted attaching?

Comment: Could you find that file in your local machine? I could find it in my VS2017 of windows 10: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.10.25017\crt\src\vcruntime.

Comment: @JackZhai-MSFT Thanks but I cannot find it (dir /s exe_common.inl). I have the *C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC* folder, but not the *...\VC\Tools* folder at all, maybe because I have not installed VC/VC++. Do I have to? I also have not yet uninstalled the previous version *C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0* - though that's not supposed to matter.

Comment: I use the VS2017 in windows 10 64 bit, and it was in the folder Program Files (x86) not Program Files path, if you really visit the correct VS2017 setup path, but has no this file, I agree with you, it would be the VS setup issue. You'd better to enable the package which was related to the VC++ during you install it.